# HBase High Availability without Namenode High Availability

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, high-availability, ambari, namenode

I've set up a two node cluster using Ambari with HBase installed. I know that we can't achieve Namenode HA without three nodes. But can we make HBase high available with two nodes, by just adding a Standby HBase Master. Does Hbase high availability depend on Namenode high availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make HBase HA with just two Hbase Masters. However, Hbase will go down if your single Namenode goes down since Hbase depends on HDFS to work.

Comment: Some useful comments can be found here : https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/117939/hbase-high-availability-minimum-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the virtual SAN solutions to provide HA NFS share for your cluster? Two nodes should be enough for such configuration.